# I need to read file .sav into R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a .*sav* file into R.

First of all, I tried using the package *haven*

```
library(haven) 
read_sav("dataset.sav")
```

But I got the following warning:

> Erro: Failed to parse C:/dataset.SAV: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.

Secondly, I used the package *foreign*.

```
library("foreign")
data2 <- read.spss("dataset.sav")
```

But I got the following warning:

> Error in read.spss("dataset.sav") :    file 'dataset.sav' is not in
> any supported SPSS format

Could someone tell me how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Carvalho

Comment: The file does not appear to be an SPSS file (nor an IDL file, which also commonly uses the `.sav` extension).  You'll have to figure out how the file was produced before you can do much more.

Comment: Check whether the file is dataset.sav (code) or dataset.SAV (error message)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I checked type of my .sav file in checkfiletype.com and I found out that my .sav file is actually an ASCII txt file. check out this page: https://www.pippanorris.com/data and download "Data in SPSS" file which is a .sav file. if you can read this file without any problem, surely the problem comes from your original .sav file.